# Not Getting Twitter Highlights/Recommendations

Tags: twitter, notifications

I have two Twitter accounts. Account #2 "recommends" tweets via in-app/push notifications and sends "highlights" push notifications but my Primary account only sends recommendation notifications (no highlights) but they don't show up in-app. All other notifications work well for both accounts on both iPhone and iPad.

I have both features turned on in "Push Notifications" settings on both iPhone and iPad. I've had this issue for months, it hasn't resolved itself. I've read the articles about both features on Twitter's website but they don't offer much trouble-shooting. No response from Twitter support.

Do I need to erase my login info from both devices, delete both apps, and start over again or is there a better solution?

Comment: Since your issue is with the notifications from it iOS app, you should really ask this at [apple.se]. Web Apps is really only concerned with the web interface.

Comment: @ale Great idea! http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266404/not-getting-twitter-highlights-recommendations-on-ios

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been re-asked on the appropriate site.